# How should I get location information in a website or mobile device?

Tags: mobile, web-app

I've created a website that stores location information for certain places: for example, basketball courts.

I'm looking for a way to allow users to add location information (to the exact GPS coordinates) that is easy to use. I currently offer two choices:

1. Enter address and have Google search it and place it on a map
2. Use my current GPS coordinates

Problem with 1. is that you can't expect people to know the street addresses of... anything basically. Most people only know the address of their home and maybe their work.

Obviously 2. fails if you aren't at the location you are adding.

Is there any standard or common way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could offer a third option - the user could put a pin on a map.  I know where my local basketball court is and could place it on a map, this way I do not have to know the address.

Comment: I ended up having users enter an address to search, then allow them to drag a pin and place it.